# get Map center on android google maps v1

Tags: android, google-maps

First of all, i already know that google maps v1 api was deprecated 2 years ago, but im developing a map with amazon sdk, wich maps api is identical to google maps v1.

For those who don't know it, here it is:
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/maps

What i need to do is to get de coords of the center of the map at the current view.

I'm using the MapView.getMapCenter() but it retrieves a GeoPoint that makes no sense as global coords at all.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GeoPoint has methods getLatitudeE6 and the corresponding one for longitude which return the lat/long in micro degrees. So divide them by a million to get the result in the normal degrees units.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Thanks!